# Simple Validate PHP

Tags: php, validation

this is my very first topic so bear with me. 
I'm still learning how to validate but I really need your help.

I need to validate first name, last name, street, suburb, postcode, email, status and date of birth.

If I do this way:

```
if (empty($firstname)) {$errors[] =" First Name Can not be Empty <br> ";}
if (empty($lastname)) {$errors[] =" Last Name Can not be Empty <br> ";}
if (empty($street)) {$errors[] =" Street Can not be Empty <br> ";}
if (empty($suburb)) {$errors[] =" Suburb Can not be Empty <br> ";}
if (empty($postcode)) {$errors[] =" Postcode Can not be Empty <br> ";}
//    elseif (!is_numeric($postcode)) {$errors[] =" Postcode must be numeric ";}
    elseif(!preg_match("/\^\(\[0\-9\]\{5\}\(\[\-\\s\]\?\[0\-9\]\{4\}\)\?\)\$/", $postcode))  {$errors[] =" Please enter a valid post number <br> ";}
if( !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $myemail) )  {$errors[] =" You have entered and invalid email address <br> ";}
if (empty($DOB)) {$errors[] =" Date only <br> ";}
```

It gave me heaps of errors.

This is my full PHP code:

```
    <?php

 function renderForm($first, $last, $st, $sub, $pcode, $em, $sta, $dofb, $error)
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Add Student</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 

 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 echo "<p><b>Add new student details</b></p>";
 ?> 
 <form action="" method="post">
 <div>
 <strong>First name: </strong> <input type="text" name="FNAME" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Last name: </strong> <input type="text" name="LNAME" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Street: </strong> <input type="text" name="STREET" value="<?php echo $st; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Suburb: </strong> <input type="text" name="SUBURB" value="<?php echo $sub; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Postcode: </strong> <input type="text" name="POSTCODE" value="<?php echo $pcode; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Email: </strong> <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="<?php echo $em; ?>" /><br/> 
 <strong>Status: </strong> <input type="text" name="STATUS" value="<?php echo $sta; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Date of Birth: </strong> <input type="text" name="DOB" value="<?php echo $dofb; ?>" /><br/>
 <p>Required Field</p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </form> 
 <p><a href="view.php">Update & delete students</a></p>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php 
 }

 include('dbconnect.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['FNAME']));
 $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['LNAME']));
 $street = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['STREET']));
 $suburb = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['SUBURB']));
 $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['POSTCODE']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['EMAIL']));
 $status = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['STATUS']));
 $dob = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['DOB']));

 if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $street == '' || $suburb == '' || $postcode == '' || $email == '' || $status == '' || $dob == '')
 {

 $error = 'Your field is empty';

 renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $street, $suburb, $postcode, $email, $status, $dob, $error);
 }
 else
 {

 mysql_query("INSERT student SET FNAME='$firstname', LNAME='$lastname', STREET='$street', SUBURB='$suburb', POSTCODE='$postcode', EMAIL='$email', STATUS='$status', DOB='$dob' ")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
 }
 else

 {
 renderForm('','','','','','','','','');
 }
?>
```

I don't know what do to and I'm really confused so I was wondering if you could help me out? Yes, I've searched everywhere and followed some tutorials even answers on this site but it doesn't work. I'm still struggling. 
Your help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

EDIT: Link: http://viper-7.com/HfyXw3
link for dbconnect: http://viper-7.com/14PG1H

Comment: "It gave me heaps of errors" — What errors?

Comment: where have you defined this funtion "renderForm"

Comment: Okay now there is no errors. Finally! But, when I enter all forms, the error message still says "Your field is empty" ?

Comment: which field does it say is empty?

Comment: 1. As @alagu  mentioned where is you function defined.              2. This is the old way of doing ,PHP has changed now do some OOP way  it is easy than this. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: All fields and yes Ive put everything in.

Comment: It may be easier to use a 'validation' library of which there are few for PHP. Internet search: 'php validation library' returns a few useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

try making an array of the fields as so:

```
$fields = array(
    'fname' => $_POST['fname'],
    'lname' => $_POST['lname'],
    'street' => $_POST['street'],
    'suburb' => $_POST['suburb'],
    'postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'status' => $_POST['status'],
    'dob' => $_POST['dob']
);

foreach( $fields as $field )
{
    if( empty($field) )
    {
        $errors[] = "Your field is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know where to put that and also I don't know what to delete my other codes.

Answer (score 0):

With everything I suggested: http://viper-7.com/3JSTyP should now work but cannot test

Why are you emptying the form with `renderForm`? Remove from the top of your page:

```
<?php
    function renderForm($first, $last, $st, $sub, $pcode, $em, $sta, $dofb, $error) {
?>
```

Remove the `}` at the beginning of your second PHP script.

Also remove the final else statement:

```
else {
    renderForm('','','','','','','','','');
}
```

Then finally put in the action part of the form:

```
"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

EDIT:

Add (at the top of the page):

```
$error = $firstname = $lastname = $street = $suburb = $postcode = $email = $status = $dob = '';
```

to declare the variables and then in the form itself change each one to match the variable (e.g.):

```
$first = $firstname
```

Comment: @imn00b try that now.

Comment: @imn00b yes, so where you declared the other variables `$firstname = $lastname = etc...` add `$error = $firstname = $lastname = etc...`

Comment: I deleted that and this error came up: 
Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\assessmentCMS\admin\students\add.php on line 55

line 55 code is:  echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Don't delete that line just declare `$error` with the other variables at the top of the page (see the EDIT section of my answer).

Comment: Nup doesnt work :/ http://prntscr.com/4tjfb2

Is there any way I can send you my folder?

Comment: Paste all your current code in http://viper-7.com/ hit paste and put the link in your question.

Comment: added the link at the bottom of my thread. you need other file such as dbconnect.php =/

Comment: added another link for dbconnect.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply validate the street name since it may differ from country to country or city to city!
so i think just using:

```
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['FNAME']));
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['LNAME']));
$street = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['STREET']));
$suburb = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['SUBURB']));
```

for validating email you can use:

```
preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email);
```

and for validating post code, it agains depends on what country you wanna check for!!!
these regexes may help you:

```
Afghanistan,Angola,Belize,Benin,Hong Kong,Ireland, Macau
no Postal Code

Argentina
^[A-Z][0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}$

Canada
^(?!.*[DFIOQU].*)([A-Z][0-9]){3}$       

US
^[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})?$

UK
^[A-Z]?[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]?\s[0-9][A-Z]{2}$


Latvia
^LV[-\s]?[\d]{4}$

Hungary,Denmark,Cyprus,Georgia,Bangladesh,Austria,Armenia,Australia,Albania,Belgium,Bulgaria,Cape   Verde,Philippines,Paraguay
Norway,New Zealand,Liechtenstein,Luxembourg,South Africa,Tunisia,Switzerland
^[\d]{4}$

Netherlands
^[\d]{4}\s[A-Z]{2}$

Portugal
^[\d]{4}[\s-][\d]{3}$

Israel,Iraq,Indonesia,Greece,Germany,Guam,Croatia,Costa    Rica,Estonia,Egypt,France,Finland,American Samoa,Algeria
 Brazil,Bosnia and Herzegovina,Cambodia,Palau,Morocco,Montenegro,Northern Mariana  Islands,Lithuania,Italy,Malaysia
 Mexico,Marshall Islands,Micronesia,Serbia,Puerto Rico,San Marino,Taiwan,Thailand,Spain,Sri L  anka,Turkey,Ukraine,U.S. Virgin Islands,Vatican
^[\d]{5}$

 Poland
 ^[\d]{2}[\s-]?[\d]{3}$

Czech Republic, Slovakia, Sweden
^[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{2}$

Iran
^[\d]{5}[\s-][\d]{5}$


China,Colombia,Belarus,Panama,Pakistan,Nigeria,Kazakhstan,Singapore,Romania,Russia
^[\d]{6}$
```

just a preg_match() with these pattern will do your validation!